# Find all functions with gradient equal to

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $(y-z^2,x+z,-2xz+y)$

$ ∫ \frac{∂f}{∂x} = yx-z^2x +h(y,z)$ $\Rightarrow $ $\frac{∂f}{∂y} = x$ $\Rightarrow $  z$\Rightarrow $

$∫ \frac{∂f}{∂y} = zy$ $\Rightarrow $  $yx-z^2x+zy+h(z)$

$∫ \frac{∂f}{∂y} = xy+zy$ $\Rightarrow $  $ \frac{∂f}{∂z}  = y$

$-2xz $$\Rightarrow $  $∫ \frac{∂f}{∂z} = -xz^2 +C $

$f(x,y,z) = yx-z^2x+zy-xz^2+C$

My question is this, how does one find the function correctly, because I got the wrong answer, now I do not know what do do.

Comment: In first step you miss $x$, must be yx-xz^2

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{r@{~}c@{~}l l}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =y-z^2&\implies&     f(x,y,z) = xy-xz^2+u(y,z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =x+z&\implies&     f(x,y,z) = xy+yz+v(x,z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =-2zx +y &\implies&     f(x,y,z) = -xz^2+yz + w(x,y)\\
\end{array}$$

so $w(x,y)=xy\; ; v(x,z)= -xz^2 \text{ and }u(y,z) = yz$

$$f(x,y,z) = xy-xz^2+yz+C$$

Comment: What would be the final answer?

Comment: final answer edited in

Comment: I could be wrong but why is not $ xy -2xz^2+yz +C$ ?

Comment: if it were as you say then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= y-2z^2 $ instead of $y-z^2$